# _CrtMemDumpAllObjectsSince() function is not able to detect leaks if delete array called instead of delete []array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-leaks, delete-operator

Here is some sample code:

```
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <windows.h>

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_CLIENTBLOCK
#endif

int main()   
{
   int* arr = new int[10];
   delete arr;     //not using delete [] arr
   _CrtMemDumpAllObjectsSince(NULL); // dumping leak logs 


  return 0;
}
```

As you can see that I have not used `delete [] arr` and still I did not get any leaks.

Can anyone please correct it and explain me why `_CrtMemDumpAllObjectsSince()` is not dumping leaks in above code.

Answer (score 3):

The official answer is that pairing `new[]` with `delete` gives undefined behavior, so you can't count on anything useful happening from that point onward.

The unofficial answer that's generally more helpful is that when you do this (`new[]` with `delete`) what normally happens is that the memory block gets returned to the heap, *but* the destructors don't get invoked on the objects in the array. In other words, those objects aren't properly destroyed, *but* the memory the occupied gets freed. Since it's only checking that blocks of memory have been freed (and has no knowledge of dtors), `_CrtMemDumpAllObjectsSince()` won't notice any problem.

On the other hand, consider something like this:

```
class stupid {
    char *junk;
public:
    stupid() { junk = new char[10]; }
    ~stupid() { delete [] junk; }
};

int main() {
    stupid *stuff = new stupid[10];

    delete stuff;
    // delete [] stuff;
    _CrtMemDumpAllObjectsSince(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

This will probably leak memory as-is, but quit leaking it when you use the `delete [] stuff;` instead of `delete stuff;` (actually, doing a quick check, I find that at least for me it flat-out crashes as-is, so you still may not get a leak report, but you'll definitely know something's wrong in a hurry).

Comment: thanks jerry. I just have one more doubt why program crashes in your example. Although I got the alert there is something wrong...

Comment: @ShashankJain: I'm honestly not sure -- I expected it to run, but produce a memory leak. I suspect figuring out exactly what's going on would be non-trivial, and I'm not willing to spend a lot of time on figuring out why it's happening, especially since I virtually never use `new []` at all any more (and haven't done so in years).

Answer (score 0):

Visual c++'s delete operator used on an array is documented as having unpredictable results. I think because youve got an array of ints the memory is being correctly freed because each element int the array has no side effects if not destroyed.

Try doing the same thing with an array of user defined types where each object allocates its own memory for something and frees it in the destructor. I believe you'll have different results.